# Best way to visualize clusters

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

Not sure if this is the right exchange to post this question but please feel free to redirect me.

I have a bunch of clusters each with a title and a bunch of items associated with it. What is the best/easiet way to visualize it?

```
[{
  title: "Title1",
  items: [ "a", "b", "c"]
},
{
  title: "Title2",
  items: [ "c", "d", "e"]
},
...]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are there millions of items for each title? Are you looking to visualize the similarity?

Comment: One place to ask would be [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization), similar questions seem to have gotten very helpful answers there. :)

Comment: @lime I can sample the items to be be reasonably small (say 100)

Answer (score 1):

My go-to way to visualize data is [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/). It's pretty simple to learn, and can generate some nice graphs. They aren't pretty, but they are very functional.

For example, see here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/